# 10-seconds count-up timer / vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <style>
    div#app { padding: 30px; margin: 30px auto; width: 300px; text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #ccc; box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaa; }
    div#time { font-size: 25pt; padding: 5px; margin: 0px auto; background: #ccc;
      width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
</head>
```

I have a working 10 seconds count up timer in vue.js using moment() method, and few thing still not work. I want to set clearInterval when 10seconds after from current time, but it never stops.
I tried both variable 'count' and clearInterval().
Anyone can help?

```js
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>counter1</h1>
    <div id="time">{{ time }}</div>
  </div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count=0;
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        time: "0",
        count:0
      },
      mounted() {
          this.startTime = moment();
          let callback = () => {
            let time_diff = moment().diff(this.startTime);
            this.time = moment.utc(time_diff).format("s");
            this.running=true;
            

            
          };
        let interval= () =>{ setInterval(callback, 1000);
            ++count;
            if(count==10) clearInterval(interval);
        }

          interval();
         
        }
    })
   </script>
```

Comment: You need to clear the interval with what `setInterval` returns, not with the function that you create around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining the interval like so:

```js
let interval= () =>{ setInterval(callback, 1000);
```

`interval` contains a function, rapped around the `setInterval`. To cancel the intenrval, we'll need to assign the result value, not in a deeper function.

After removing the function, it can look something like this working demo:

```js
var count=0;
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        time: "0",
        count:0
    },
    mounted() {

        // Create startTime
        this.startTime = moment();

        // Define callback
        let callback = () => {

            // Calculate time diff
            let time_diff = moment().diff(this.startTime);
            this.time = moment.utc(time_diff).format("s");
            this.running=true;

            // Bumb counter
            ++count;

            // Clear interval on count==10
            if (count==10) clearInterval(interval);
        };

        // Start interval
        let interval = setInterval(callback, 1000);
    }
})
```

```css
div#app  { padding: 30px; margin: 30px auto; width: 300px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaa; }
div#time { font-size: 25pt; padding: 5px; margin: 0px auto; background: #ccc; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }

/* Hide console wrapper */
.as-console-wrapper { display: none !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>counter1</h1>
  <div id="time">{{ time }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We should clear the interval ID returned by `setInterval`, just like below:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count=0;
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        time: "0",
        count:0
      },
      mounted() {
          this.startTime = moment();

          let interval;
          let callback = () => {
            let time_diff = moment().diff(this.startTime);
            this.time = moment.utc(time_diff).format("s");
            this.running=true;

            ++count;
            if(count == 10) clearInterval(interval);            
          };

          interval = setInterval(callback, 1000)
    })
</script>
```

You can get more info from [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) .